# Add a feature to my image gallery that allows images to open in new window

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, grid-layout

I've built an image gallery that lets you click on a thumbnail in a grid which activates it to pop up with a larger version of the image and an image description - however what I want to do now is add the ability to click on the larger image and have it open the image in a new tab (ideally with a simple target _blank link) but I can't figure out how to add it to my current code...

If anyone could give me some advice it would be hugely appreciated! I'll attach a fiddle so you can see the code and the link to the actual page on the site I'm having trouble with!

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="content">
         <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid__item" data-size="1680x2520">
               <a href="img/original/big1.jpg" class="img-wrap">
                  <img src="img/thumbs/big1.jpg" alt="Big 1" />
                  <div class="description description--grid">
                     <h3>Chemical Field I</h3>
                     <p>Chemical on Paper <em>70 x 100cm</em></p>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="grid__item" data-size="1680x2520">
               <a href="img/original/big2.jpg" class="img-wrap">
                  <img src="img/thumbs/big2.jpg" alt="Big 2" />
                  <div class="description description--grid">
                     <h3>Chemical Field II</h3>
                     <p>Chemical on Paper <em>70 x 100cm</em></p>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="grid__item" data-size="1680x2520">
               <a href="img/original/big3.jpg" class="img-wrap">
                  <img src="img/thumbs/big3.jpg" alt="Big 3" />
                  <div class="description description--grid">
                     <h3>Chemical Field III</h3>
                     <p>Chemical on Paper <em>70 x 100cm</em></p>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    margin-left: 220px;
    width: calc(100%-220px);
}

.grid {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 7px;
}

.js .grid::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #fff url(../img/loading.svg) no-repeat 50% 75px;
    background-size: 60px auto;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.js .grid--loaded::after {
    opacity: 0;
}

.grid__item {
    width: 259.5px;
    padding: 14px;
}

.grid__item--current {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

.img-wrap {
    display: block;
}

.img-wrap:focus,
.img-wrap:hover {
    outline: none;
}

.img-wrap img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.preview {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.preview::before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
    transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.preview--open {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.preview--open::before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.clone {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 110;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.original {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 120;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.preview--open .animate {
    /* open */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.6s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.animate {
    /* close */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.description {
    color: #000;
}

.js .description--grid {
    display: none;
}

.description--preview {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 140;
    width: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 1em;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
}

.preview--open .description--preview {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.description--preview h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.description--preview p {
    font-size: 0.65em;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.description--preview p em {
    color: #5D5D5D;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.4em 0 0 0;
}


/* Details */

.details {
    max-width: 100%;
    /* IE 10-11 bug flexbox */
}

.details ul {
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.details ul li {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    padding: 0.15em 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s, opacity 1s;
    transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
}

.preview--open .details ul li {

    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.preview--open .details ul li:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.preview--open .details ul li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.preview--open .details ul li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.preview--open .details ul li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.preview--open .details ul li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.details ul li:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #909090;
}

.icon {
    font-family: 'camera-icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: none;
    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    speak: none;
}

.icon + span {
    margin-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-focal_length:before {
    content: '\e600';
}

.icon-exposure_time:before {
    content: '\e601';
}

.icon-iso:before {
    content: '\e602';
}

.icon-camera:before {
    content: '\e603';
}

.icon-aperture:before {
    content: '\e604';
}

.details .icon {
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #000;
}


/* Close button */

.action {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

.action:hover,
.action:focus {
    color: #CCC;
    outline: none;
}

.action--close {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 150;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 1);
}

.preview--image-loaded .action--close {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

.text-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    color: transparent;
}
```

http://benedictbuckle.co.za/chemical-works.html

https://jsfiddle.net/1r6br1th/

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Add `target="_blank"` to your images <a> html

Answer (score 1):

Just added **target="_blank"** to the first **a tag** and it worked.

```
       <a href="http://benedictbuckle.co.za/img/original/big1.jpg" class="img-wrap" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://benedictbuckle.co.za/img/thumbs/big1.jpg" alt="Big 1" />
          <div class="description description--grid">
             <h3>Chemical Field I</h3>
             <p>Chemical on Paper <em>70 x 100cm</em></p>
          </div>
       </a>
```

Click the first image: https://jsfiddle.net/1r6br1th/1/

Comment: No, I'm afraid that's not what I'm needing, if you have a look at the actual site link I still need the enlarged image to open with the description next to it like it does - I then want to be able to click on just the enlarged image (not the thumbnail) and have it open that image in a new window. Thanks though and sorry if my explanation wasn't too clear.

Comment: One of your .js dynamically generates the preview layer. You could wrap the generated <img> (.original) with <a> tags. (http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) Then you could take the src of the <img> and use it for your href...(http://api.jquery.com/attr/) Other option is to change/extend the js plugin.